# How to Remove Column from Laravel Collection variable

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to move values from temp table to main table after approval.

But, I don't have status, cancelled, and cancelled by columns in main table it's only available in the temp table. So, if I try to move all the fields from temp table to main table, it's showing error.

[image]

I am trying to move using the below codes.

```
public function approve(mpd_temp $mpd)
{

$result = mpd::insert($mpd->toArray());

if ($result) {
    mpd_temp::where('sno', $mpd->sno)->delete();
    toast('MPD Successfully Approved', 'success');
}

}
```

I have tried

```
$mpd->forget('status');
$mpd->forget('cancelled_at');
$mpd->forget('cancelledby');
```

But it's showing
[image]

Is there any best way to move columns from temp table to main table and delete from temp after insert?

Comment: try to `unset($mpd->cancelledby)` (I'm not sure if that's gonna work). Or you could use `array_except()`.

Comment: unset($mpd->cancelledby) worked thank you so much! :)

Comment: I will post that as an answer.

Comment: You could simply try: `$mpd->push('approved_at', now());`

Comment: It's showing Call to undefined method App\Models\admin\mpd_temp::transform()

Comment: I have tried $mpd->push('approved_at', now()); but it's not adding value into the attributes[];

Comment: Google "add key to laravel collection" and try everything that seems to be working for you.

Comment: I just did like $mpd->approved_at = now(); it worked  

Comment: Happy to hear.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must `unset()` the key you want to remove. In your case you must do

```
unset($mpd->cancelledby);
```

And it should be removed from the collection.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **except** function on your collection:

```
$mpd->except(['status', 'cancelled_at', 'cancelledby']);
```

Comment: Yeah this will work too.

Comment: I have tried except but it's showing BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\Models\admin\mpd_temp::except()

Comment: @LokeshM So your $mpd is not a Collection!

Comment: Got it, I have tried collect($mpd)->except(['status', 'cancelled_at', 'cancelledby']); this worked.